# String vs vector to store large texts

Tags: c++, text, storage

For data compression, I need to open files (here text files) and to store all their content in variables.

Is it better to use strings or vectors of chars to store really large texts (millions or more characters)?

By better, I mean faster to loop over every character, and also faster to use the `count` function to count how many occurrences of a given character there are in the text.

Size is not really an issue here as both string and vector can store a lot of characters, and I can if necessary broke the text into a few subtexts.

Comment: Actual performance would depend on the particular C++ implementation. There is no material difference between strings and vectors in that regard. Both are random access containers, that provide comparable capabilities. You're going to spend more time trying to figure this out then you could possibly hope to save by picking the allegedly most optimal container.

Comment: In practice, there's most likely no difference at all. Both types provide forward iterators, that are (usually) implemented as pointers. The only semantic difference is, that readers of your code are more likely to expect `NUL` characters embedded in the controlled sequence for a `vector`. Since you are dealing with text files, that's not an issue, though.

Comment: Your bottleneck is not the container in memory, but file I/O.  You will want to use a container that you can either *resize* or set the capacity during construction.  Reallocating memory while reading from a file is very slow.

Answer (score 4):

since vector and string performance is implementation dependent there is no definitive answer. i suggest that you benchmark these actions in your environment and choose.

[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_QO1nm7uJs) is a very nice lecture about benchmarking your code and how even the standard cannot always suggest the right tools.

The punchline of the talk being that performance can change drastically and unpredictably - in one example an instantiation moved inside a loop actually cut running time by 80% by kicking in compiler optimization.

if you really care about performance always measure yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it better to use strings or vectors of chars to store really large texts (millions or more characters)?
>
> (here text files)

`std::string` is appropriate for textual data. Mostly due to convention, and also because it provides some rudimentary tools for processing of character strings, which `std::vector` does not.

> By better, I mean faster to loop over every character, and also faster to use the count function to count how many occurrences of a given character there are in the text.

By these metrics, both string and vector are comparable and practically the same, although exact performance is implementation specific.